# Hybrid asp.net webform / mvc app - Using asp.net controls/user controls inside mvc view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls, partial-views

I have a hybrid asp.net webform / mvc app, is there a way to use the asp.net controls and user controls inside mvc view?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather move them over to HTML helpers/partials/etc?! It'll be much nicer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *some* asp.net controls, if they don't depend upon ViewState, which doesn't exist in an MVC view.

Comment: How can you use asp.net controls in MVC?

Comment: We know we can the question was how

Comment: @JoshBerke You use them the exact same way as in a web form. What have you tried?